# Finding a transformation matrix of rotating an axis

Tags: linear-algebra

So I want to find the transformation matrix that will rotate the z axis 45 degrees toward the x axis around the y axis.

I sketched everything out and got the following matrix:
$$M=\begin{bmatrix} \cos45&0&\sin45 \\0&1&0\\-\sin45&0&\cos45   \end{bmatrix}$$
I am pretty sure this is correct, I just want to make sure that this is for the correct direction.  I may need to swap the negative signs but I do not think so.

Comment: Did you test it? What is the result of $M$ applied to the $z$-axis?